# How to determine the difference between the lists?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
first_list = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Other Name')]
second_list = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Name C'), ('D', 'Name D')]
```

I want such list: `third_list = [('D', 'Name D')]`

I used: `third_list = list(set(second_list) ^ set(first_list))` but it return me: `third_list = [('C', 'Name C'), ('D', 'Name D')]`.

So as you can see I want list where first items of tuples are different. `('C', 'Other Name')` and `('C', 'Name C')` must be the same cause there first items in tuples are the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Check online demo](https://repl.it/Hal3/1)

```
first_list = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Other Name')]
second_list = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Name C'), ('D', 'Name D')]

first_dict = dict(first_list)
second_dict = dict(second_list)
value = { k : second_dict[k] for k in set(second_dict) - set(first_dict) }
print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
first_second = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Other Name')]
second_second = [('A', 'Name A'), ('B', 'Name B'), ('C', 'Name C'), ('D', 'Name D')]
d_one=dict(first_second)
d_two=dict(second_second)
res=[(i,j) for i,j in d_two.items() if i in set(d_two).symmetric_difference(set(d_one)) ]
```

Then `res` is

```
[('D', 'Name D')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x for x in second_list if x[0] not in dict(first_list)]

[('D', 'Name D')]
```

Comment: `zip(*first_list)[0]` is a pretty non-obvious way to write `[x[0] for x in first_list]`. A shorter and more efficient version would be `dict(first_list)`.

Comment: I guess you also need to return items that are in first_list but not in second_list?